# if statement multiple conditions for id

Tags: php

I have a database table that is called roles. and it contains 5 roles and has id from 1 to 5, I have gotten the code below to work with 1 id only but want to add more without re using the entire block. so if id equals 3,4,5 show the link. can I add multiple id's in the if?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {      
    $RoleID = $row['RoleID'];

    if ($RoleID == 3) {                                        
        echo '<li><a href="/admin/index.php"><span>Admin Area</span></a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($RoleID == 3 || $RoleID == 4 || $RoleID == 5) {` really you should have just tried it if you did not yet know it is possible. SO is not a replacement for reading the manual

Comment: if($RoleID >= 1)

Comment: I did try that but it was a little different and I was going in circles

Answer (score 4):

I guess you can use `in_array`:

```
$admin_array = [3,4,5];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {      
   if (in_array($row['RoleID'], $admin_array) {                                        
       echo '<li><a href="/admin/index.php"><span>Admin Area</span></a></li>';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you 
I have used in_array() function

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {      
        $RoleID = $row['RoleID'];

        if (in_array($RoleID,array(3,4,5))) {                                        
            echo '<li><a href="/admin/index.php"><span>Admin Area</span></a></li>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no difference between this and what @Pedro has

Answer (score 0):

Something that will give some added flexibility when say you want an id to do something similar but maybe end in the same way is to use a switch case.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {      
    switch($row['RoleID']) {
        case 1:
            //Id 1 logic only
            break;
        case 2:
            //Id 2 logic only
            break;           
        case 3:
            //Without a break it will fall through.
            //Nice because if for some reason you need
            //custom for individual id do it with no break
        case 4:
        case 5:
            echo '<li><a href="/admin/index.php"><span>Admin Area</span></a></li>';
            break;
        default:
             //Do something here for instances when a ROLE ID is not found
    }
}
```